# sIFR displays only the first line of text in Opera when on transparent background

Tags: sifr, opera, transparent

I have implemented sIFR for the first time, on a test page. The code I have is below.  It works fine in IE7, Firefox, Safari and Chrome, but in Opera only the first line of sIFR-ed text appears when the page first loads and after refreshing the page.  But, if I scroll the page, all the text appears!  It seems to have to do with transparency, because if I turn transparency off, it works fine.

Please can someone help me to make this work?

Thanks,

Gary

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="sIFR-print.css" type="text/css" media="print" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="all.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

<script src="sifr.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="sifr-config.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
 var sIFRfont = {
    src: 'fontname.swf'
};
sIFR.activate(sIFRfont);
sIFR.replace(sIFRfont, { 
css: [ 
    '.sIFR-root { line-height: 1em; font-size: 64px; color: #000000; background-color: blue; text-align: left; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; text-decoration: none; visibility: hidden; }' 
], 
fitExactly      : true, 
forceClear      : true, 
forceSingleLine : false, 
selector        : 'div.flashtext', 
transparent     : true
});
//]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch SIFR for Cufon, even Shaun Inman is not using SIFR himself anymore. He uses Cufon :) http://cufon.shoqolate.com/generate/

Comment: To be fair, I don't think Shaun ever used sIFR itself. He kinda stuck to IFR.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know, but transparent Flash movies can have issues. You sure you need transparency?